# Mover un Objeto de un Array creado en un contenedor a un Array diferente Java

Tags: java, poo, contenedores

Estoy en el proceso de un código de Java Programación Orientada a Objetos, en el cual tengo **Entrenadores**, los cuales tienen **Cajas** para guardar sus **Pokemones**, uno de los requerimientos es poder mover un pokemon de una caja a otra, tengo mucha confusión en que parámetros pedir para poder hacer el cambio, el único que tengo claro, es el nombre del pokemon a cambiar.

Adjunto diagrama de clases y código de las clases que creo pueden ser involucradas.

[image: Diagrama de clases]

Link con las clases: [Código Java](https://pastebin.com/yvD56AVJ)

Al final del link anterior esta el método que quiero usar para mover los pokemones, pero lo pongo explicito aquí.

```
public boolean moverPokemonCaja(String nombrePokemon, ListaPokemon lista1, ListaPokemon lista2, Caja[] cajas) {

        if (lista1.getCantPokemons() <= 0) {
            System.out.println("No hay pokemones dentro de la caja!");
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lista1.getCantPokemons() ; i++) {
            if (lista1[i] != null && lista1[i].get) {
                lista1[i] = null;
                lista1.setCantPokemons(lista1.getCantPokemons()-1);
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    }
```

No esta demás decir que cada atributo tienes sus getter's y setter's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin el codigo completo con getters y setters esta dificil ayudarte,pero tendria que ser algo asi:

package stackoverflow;

public class Mamain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Caja caja=new Caja("Pokedex1",0,new ListaPokemon(10));
    Caja caja2=new Caja("Pokedex2",0,new ListaPokemon(10));

    cambiar(caja,caja2,0,2);




        }
        //metodo para cambiar de posicion.El parametro posicionPokemon se usa para obtener el pokemon que queremos cambiar y el de posicionACambiar para introducirlo en una posicion de la otra lista
        public static void cambiar(Caja caja1,Caja caja2,int posicionPokemon,int posicionACambiar) {
            
            //obtenemos listas pokemons de la caja 1 y de la 2
            ListaPokemon listaPokemon=caja1.getLista();
            ListaPokemon listaPokemonACambiar=caja2.getLista();
            
            //creamos un pokemon 
            listaPokemon.getPokemons()[posicionPokemon]=new Pokemon(15, "Pikachu", 2);
            //obtenemos el pokemons creado anteriormente
            Pokemon pokemonCambiar =listaPokemon.getPokemons()[posicionPokemon];
            //introducimos el pokemon en otra lista y dejamos vacia la posicion donde estaba pikachu para poder usarla luego
            listaPokemonACambiar.getPokemons()[posicionACambiar]=pokemonCambiar;
            listaPokemon.getPokemons()[posicionPokemon]=null;
            
            System.out.println(listaPokemonACambiar.getPokemons()[posicionACambiar].toString());
        }
    }
```

Funciona el codigo,lo importante no es copiar y pegar sino entender el concepto.Cualquier duda que no hayas entendido preguntame.Espero que te sirva saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si gustas puedo exportar el código desde Intellij y enviártelo, ya que las clases las tengo en archivos separados.

Comment: si,por supuesto

Comment: Lo siento por la tardanza @Santi, aqui esta el link http://www.mediafire.com/file/xnc297kbps83o3s/t2.rar/file

Comment: Ahi lo miro,si te sirvio la respuesta votala por favor